Is the GAM model structure correct?
I have read several papers using GAM to build models, including the tutorial "Hierarchical Generalized Additive Models in Ecology: An Introduction with mgcv," which I found very helpful. Based on this tutorial, I built two models (GI model and I model). However, after reading several studies on similar research topics that also use GAM, I noticed that my model structure differs from theirs.
I am posting this here in the hope that someone can help me understand whether my approach is appropriate or if there are specific reasons to adjust my model structure.
The dataset contains information about contact behavior. This is a longitudinal study conducted over two years with several waves. During each wave, participants reported how many contacts they made in the previous 24 hours. Some participants reported contact behaviour for over 20 waves. Other variables include age, gender, household size (hh_size), population density (pop_density), and bundesland_0.
The research question is how people changes their contact numbers according to lockdown measures.
Explaination for key variables are as follows:
all_contact_n: the number of contacts (how many contacts made in the last 24 hours), this is the outcome variable
lockdown: two levels: First lockdown, Relaxed measure
wave: during which wave the contact behaviour is reported
age: age of the participant
gender: male or female
hh_size: number of household members including the participant himself
week_day: the numebr of the day of contact during a week, such as Monday is 1, Tuesday is 2
job_cat: employment status, unemployed, employed, being student, retired
SES_cat: socioeconomic status
pop_denstiy: population density of the district
mask_0: whether wearing mask or not during the contact
new_id: the participant ID
bundesland_0: the state that the participant lives
A stimulated dataset is provided:
set.seed(42)

n <- 10000

# Generate the simulated dataset
data <- data.frame(
  new_id = sample(paste0("ID_", 1:7851), size = n, replace = TRUE),
  bundesland_0 = sample(c("Baden-Württemberg", "Bavaria", "Berlin", "Brandenburg", 
                          "Bremen", "Hamburg", "Hesse", "Lower Saxony", 
                          "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern", "North Rhine-Westphalia", 
                          "Rhineland-Palatinate", "Saarland", "Saxony", 
                          "Saxony-Anhalt", "Schleswig-Holstein", "Thuringia"), 
                        size = n, replace = TRUE),
  all_contact_n = rpois(n, lambda = 5),
  gender_0 = sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
  hh_size = sample(1:5, size = n, replace = TRUE),
  wave = sample(1:30, size = n, replace = TRUE),
  age = sample(18:90, size = n, replace = TRUE),
  job_cat = sample(c("Employed", "Unemployed", "Retired", "Student"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
  SES_cat = sample(c("Low", "Medium", "High"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
  pop_density = sample(c("1-19999", "20000-49999", "50000+"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
  lockdown = sample(c("First lockdown", "Relaxed measures"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
  mask_0 = sample(c("No", "Yes"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
  week_day = sample(1:7, size = n, replace = TRUE))

The reason I want to include week_day instead of weekend is that people exhibit a weekly pattern in their contact behaviors. For example, middle-aged individuals may go to work during weekdays and meet friends on weekends. In contrast, older adults might meet more people on weekends compared to weekdays.
I build two models, 1st one includes a common smoother plus group-level smoothers with differing wiggliness. 2nd one include ony group-level smoothers with differing wiggliness.
Since the research question is about how the lockdown affects people’s contact behavior, I use the lockdown variable with the by argument to fit separate smoothers for the two levels of lockdown.
As this is a repeated-measures study where some participants reported data for multiple wave, I include participant ID (new_id) as a random effect. The rationale for including bundesland_0 as a random effect is similar.
mod1 <- bam(all_contact_n ~ lockdown + 
                s(age, k=10,  bs="tp", m=2) +
                s(age, by = lockdown, k=10, bs="tp", m=1) + 
                s(hh_size, k=7, m=2) + 
                s(hh_size, by = lockdown, k=7, bs="tp", m=1) +
                s(week_day, bs="cc", k=7, m=2) + 
                s(week_day, by = lockdown, bs="cc", k=7, m=1) +
                gender_0 +
                s(gender_0, by = lockdown, bs = "fs", k = 2) + 
                job_cat +
                s(job_cat, by = lockdown, bs = "fs", k = 4) +
                SES_cat+
                s(SES_cat, by = lockdown, bs = "fs", k = 3) +
                pop_density + 
                s(pop_density, by = lockdown, bs = "fs", k = 3) +
                mask_0 +
                s(mask_0, by = lockdown, bs = "fs", k = 2) +
                s(new_id, bs = "re", k = 100) +
                s(bundesland_0, bs = "re", k = 5),
              data = data, method = "fREML", family = "poisson",
              knots = list(week_day = c(0, 7)))

mod2 <- bam(all_contact_n ~ lockdown + 
                s(age, by = lockdown, k=5, bs="tp", m=1) +
                s(hh_size, by = lockdown, k=5, bs="tp", m=1) +
                s(week_day, by = lockdown, bs="cc", k=7, m=1) +
                s(gender_0, by = lockdown, bs = "fs", k = 2) + 
                s(job_cat, by = lockdown, bs = "fs", k = 4) + 
                s(SES_cat, by = lockdown, bs = "fs", k = 3) +
                s(pop_density, by = lockdown, bs = "fs", k = 3) +
                s(mask_0, by = lockdown, bs = "fs", k = 2) +
                s(new_id, bs = "re", k = 100) +
                s(bundesland_0, bs = "re", k = 5),
              data = data, method = "fREML", family = "poisson",
              knots = list(week_day = c(0, 7)))

Question 1: The results of the two models are not similar, and the 2nd model seems to be more proper. For example, in the results of the first model, like the main effect of mask is siginificantly asscoatied with higher contact number, but the effect are not siginificant for both lockdown and relaxed period. From the tutorial, a GI model seems to be better, but from this dataset and research question, the I model seems to be better. Is this possible?
Question 2: I tried to add interaction terms, such as the interaction between age, week_day, and lockdown, but the computation time is long and interpretation is not straightforward. Is this a good reason to reject the interaction terms?
Question 3: From this post, which is also a longitudinal study, it is suggested to handle the repeated measures like this
s(Timepoint, Subject, bs = "fs", k = 10), do I need to change my model to include wave like this?
Question 4: I remember that GAM is recommanded for analysis when the independent variables are continous variabels, or most of them. I read another paper, A Population Level Study on the Determinants of COVID-19 Vaccine Hesitancy at the U.S. County Level, and in this paper the GAM was built using continous variables, then results of different sub models (urban or rural) are compared. So instead of including the factor variables in one model, it build sub models seperately according to the factor variable, then compare the results of sub models. Is this a better way to use the GAM model?
